# Change physical keyboard on Samsung ultrabooks with one using a different layout possible

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ultrabook

Planning to get a Samsung NP900X4D-A01ES, where the last two letters state it is the Spanish version of this model. I am able to get a crazy deal for this machine, but I plan to use it for programming and would love to have a US keyboard. I found one on eBay, but I wonder if the process is as easy as physically swapping the keyboard with the US one.

Edit: I am not talking about the physical layout of the keyboard. A new front shield will also have to be pruchased with the keyboard. I am asking if the keyboards have the same interface with the mb and the mb will recognize the new layout.

I am a handy person, and have no issue with the swap itself, just want to know if anyone had experience or knows if the keyboard on Samsung laptops are interchangeable.

To preempt questions regarding why I want to do this, or suggesting I would eventually get used to the Spanish layout, I simply love looking at the US layout and like my stuff to look like they were designed, so stickers will not cut it.

Answer (score -1):

I dont have experience with that brand and model.  But, in my experience with Dell Latitudes, the European keyboard has a different physical layout than the US version of the same model.  The US keyboard would *not* physically fit in the space for the European version and vice versa.

Your best bet would be to call Samsung support and ask if it is possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Somehow i've missed it. I am not talking about the physical layout of the keyboard. A new front shield will also have to be purchased with the keyboard. I am asking if the keyboards have the same interface with the mb and the mb will recognize the new layout.

Anyway since my post I kind of got used to the spanish layout. Maybe also because I mainly use an external keyboard anyway.